# How to properly use async in forEach in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I am using this forEach loop to push some data into array and send that to client side

```
   var arrayToSend = []  //Empty Array

   SomeArray.forEach(function(item){
        Collection.findById(item.id,function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {

            arrayToSend.push(data.record)
          }
  //How can I run this next line at end of loop  asynchronously
         res.render("index",{arrayToSend : arrayToSend })
        })
      })


    }
```

How can I use async to run **res.render("index",{arrayToSend : arrayToSend })** after an loop end within forEach scope in form of callback,otherwise if I run this outside the loop it will send empty array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.forEach`, use `.map` to map each item in `someArray` to a Promise, so that you can create an array of Promises. If you call `Promise.all` on that array, you'll get a Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the array have resolved.

Because `findById` is callback-based, not Promise-based, you need to transform each callback into a Promise first:

```
const promises = someArray.map((item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Collection.findById(item.id, (err,data) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    resolve(data.record);
  });
}));
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(arrayToSend => {
    res.render("index", { arrayToSend });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

If you want to tolerate errors from `findById` and still build an `arrayToSend` without the items that had errors, you can `push` to an external array (similar to what you were doing originally) and `resolve` unconditionally, whether `findById` results in an error or not:

```
const arrayToSend = [];
const promises = someArray.map((item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Collection.findById(item.id, (err,data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else arrayToSend.push(data.record);
    resolve();
  });
}));
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(() => {
    res.render("index", { arrayToSend });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked perfectly. I got your explanation too :)